# firebase init Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to get service [firebasedatabase.googleapis.com]

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I'm trying to use firebase init with package firebase, firebase-admin and firebase-tools. I've downloaded the json file from the firebase console and I've put it on the server, then i run `firebase init` function. there i choose `realtime database and use existing project`

but after that function run i get error

```
Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to get service [firebasedatabase.googleapis.com]
Help Token: ***this is help token***
```

here are the details of the results of the firebase init that I did

```
root@api:/var/www/api/public_html# firebase init

     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  /var/www/api/public_html

Before we get started, keep in mind:

  * You are currently outside your home directory

? Which Firebase features do you want to set up for this directory? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. Realtime Databas
e: Configure a security rules file for Realtime Database and (optionally) provision default instance

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

? Please select an option: Use an existing project
? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: api (Api)
i  Using project api (Api)

=== Database Setup
i  database: ensuring required API firebasedatabase.googleapis.com is enabled...

Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to get service [firebasedatabase.googleapis.com]
Help Token: ***this is help token***
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your service account has the right access rights. Try below.

1. Follow link

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=api

2. Find the member that ends with "@appspot.gserviceaccount.com", and click "edit".
3. Give it "Editor Role", or **attach** "Firebase Realtime Database Admin".
   [image]

Comment: not working for me sir do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe couple of things to check. 1. Run `firebase login` and see if you are logged in as the correct user. 2. Run `firebase projects:list` and your target project is there.

Comment: how to run ```firebase login``` in ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Um.. how are you running firebase init?

Comment: My hair follicles thank you! This is what I'd been looking for!

Comment: There are no roles Firebase Realtime Database * or anything under `database` when searching