# HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to enable service [cloudfunctions.googleapis.com]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have firebase admin permission and cloud functions admin access but even then when I try to run `firebase init functions` command it gives me following error.

`Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to enable service [runtimeconfig.googleapis.com] Help Token *******`

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69069673/firebase-init-error-http-error-403-permission-denied-to-get-service-firebase). but not sure will it work or not as I am not owner.

I am not sure what is causing this error or permission or role is missing. Please help me on this.
#AskFirebase

Answer (score 4):

I found out the issue. I had Firebase Admin and Cloud Function Admin role. But to enable any of the api user should have Owner or Editor role.

Please refer to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63337536/3779368)

**UPDATE**

Due to security reason owner of the project was not able to give me editor role. If you are in such situation than granting user following two role will allow them to perform command such as **firebase init functions**

1. Cloud Function Admin
2. Service Account User

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when deploying Cloud Functions from Cloud Build with the firebase community builder.

It turned out that I missed the "Required IAM permissions" part when following the instructions. Basically, add `Cloud Build Service Account`, `Firebase Admin` and `API Keys Admin` roles, to the the email ending with `@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually enable [Cloud Build API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudbuild.googleapis.com/) and [Artifact Registry API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/artifactregistry.googleapis.com) for the corresponding project through the Google Cloud Console

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when deploying Cloud Functions

**How to solve it?**

1. go to this link https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. in the link go to the IAM section
3. the project in which you are working on the left side of project name you see a pen, click on that and make yourself as a onwer